# How do I mock a axios post request with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, post, jestjs

I can mock a get request with:

```
mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({
    data: { mockResponse },
}));
```

But how can I mock a Post request?

Answer (score 0):

I use `MockAdapter` from `axios-mock-adapter` as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import requestGenerator, { API } from './httpClient';
// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
const mock = new MockAdapter(API);

describe('Test for api calls', () => {
  it('Should test for postReq method for Location not reachable by car', async () => {
    const mockDirectionResponse = {
      status: 'failure',
      error: 'Location not accessible by car'
    };
    mock.onPost('/route/token').reply(200, mockDirectionResponse);
    const response = await requestGenerator.postReq('/route/token');
    expect(response.data).toEqual(mockDirectionResponse);
  });
});
```